# assets images are not loading in ionic 3 in development mode Ionic Serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-serve

I am using IONIC 3.20.1 and I am facing the issue, assets images are not rendering on the browser or device as well.

The folder structure is the same while creating the sample project inside the src folder then assets then imgs.

but images are not loading on the browser after the ionic serve. I tried all the paths like below.

```
<img float-right src="../assets/imgs/user.png" /> 
<img float-right src="../../assets/imgs/user.png" /> 
<img float-right src="/assets/imgs/user.png" /> 
<img float-right src="./assets/imgs/user.png" /> 
<img float-right src="assets/imgs/user.png" />
```

but nothing is working. Please help me out here.

[Please check the link also.](http://prntscr.com/nrums0)

Comment: make sure the path is correct,try <img src="assets/imgs/company.png">

Comment: The path is correct, but not rendering on the browser. I double check the assets folder is available inside src with imgs folder and images inside.

Comment: can u reprocude with stackbliz?

Comment: try two things : 1) rename your .png file 2) use different image

Comment: @AbdulAzeem , Ok I am going to try.

Comment: @AbdulAzeem same issue, not rendering on browser

Comment: replace assets/imgs with assets/img

Comment: @AbdulAzeem , no success.  http://prntscr.com/nrv4wi

Comment: did you try .jpg image?

Comment: Using Ionic Serve it is not working in any case. I have added Cordova Tools inside the visual studio code and Cordova browser platform, then it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the things like renaming name of the images, folder name change. but didn't work in case of "Ionic Serve".

- After that, I Installed the Cordova Tools extension for Visual Studio
  Code.
- Added the configuration file. (launch.json)
- And then added browser platform using the command  'ionic cordova platform add browser'
- At last, debug the application with "RunBrowser" option
- Now the images are rendered properly
- Scrrenshot  http://prntscr.com/nrw5fr